# Retrieving non null values from multilevel DF in pandas, and combining multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to filter by the subcolumns, retrieving only non-null values where they exist by considering columns `a`+`b`, and `c`+`d`. For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('A','a'): [-1,-1,NaN,10,NaN],
                   ('A','b'): [0,1,NaN,3,NaN],
                   ('A','c'): [NaN,NaN,0,NaN,NaN],
                   ('A','d'): [NaN,NaN,2,NaN,NaN],
                   ('B','a'): [NaN,NaN,0,NaN,NaN],
                   ('B','b'): [NaN,NaN,0,NaN,NaN],
                   ('B','c'): [NaN,-10,NaN,10,20],
                   ('B','d'): [NaN,-100,NaN,100,200]
})

#out
   A                      B                    
   a     b     c    d     a      b     c      d
0  -1.0  0.0   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   2.0    0.0
2  NaN  NaN    0.0  2.0   0.0    0.0   NaN    NaN
3  10.0  3.0   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   10.0   100.0
4   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   20.0   200.0
```

My idea is to search under `A` for those columns `a`+`b`, and `c`+`d` that have non-null values, and retrieve two columns (`x` and `y`) that have the compiled data. Note that some rows may have only `NaN` for a column (which is the case of row `4` of `A`). In those cases I'd like to have a `NaN`.

I think that I would be able to get it using something like

```
pfilter=prefilesdf.notnull()
colfilter=pfilter.reindex(columns = df.columns, level=0)
out=df.mask(colfilter)
```

The desired output would be:

```
    A           B                    
    x    y      x    y
0  -1.0  0.0    NaN  NaN
1  -1.0  1.0    2.0    0.0
2  0.0   2.0    0.0    0.0
3  10.0  3.0    10.0   100.0
4  NaN   NaN    20.0   200.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for selected `df` by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
d = {'a':'L1','b':'L1','c':'L2','d':'L2'}
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.get_level_values(0),
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1).map(lambda x: d[x]),
                                        df.columns.get_level_values(1)])
print (df)
      A                   B                  
     L1        L2        L1         L2       
      a    b    c    d    a    b     c      d
0  -1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN -10.0 -100.0
2   NaN  NaN  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0   NaN    NaN
3  10.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  10.0  100.0
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  20.0  200.0
```

```
df1 = df.xs('L1', axis=1, level=1)
df2 = df.xs('L2', axis=1, level=1).rename(columns={'c':'a','d':'b'})

print (df1)

      A         B     
      a    b    a    b
0  -1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
1  -1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0
3  10.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

print (df2)
     A          B       
     a    b     a      b
0  NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
1  NaN  NaN -10.0 -100.0
2  0.0  2.0   NaN    NaN
3  NaN  NaN  10.0  100.0

print (df1.combine_first(df2))
      A          B       
      a    b     a      b
0  -1.0  0.0   NaN    NaN
1  -1.0  1.0 -10.0 -100.0
2   0.0  2.0   0.0    0.0
3  10.0  3.0  10.0  100.0
4   NaN  NaN  20.0  200.0
```